# Can't resize VirtualBox drive. Debian

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-space, gparted

I had Debian Virtual Machine with 8 Gb vdi disk. Later i need have been some extra space.

I resize vdi disk with `VBoxManage modifyhd Debian.vdi --resize 20Gb`

Next, i download [GParted ISO](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and create new Virtual Machine. Add to this machine `Debian.vdi` and `GParted ISO`. Start this machine and resize `/dev/sda1` to all memory, and recreate linux-swap.

[image]

Next, i start Debian VM and see, that Debian can't recognize new disk structure. It's still old sections and sizes.

[image]

Can you help me? How to fix this?

P.S. When restart GParted, i can see new section size. In Debian - old size.
I can't post links and photos. Sorry!

Comment: Do you have any snapshots of the Debian VM on Virtualbox? Did you read [this link](http://trivialproof.blogspot.in/2011/01/resizing-virtualbox-virtual-hard-disk.html)? According to [Virtualbox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) the value for resize parameter should be in megabytes.

Comment: Yes in megabytes, but i'm too lazy to write 20 Gb in Mb in THIS POST

Comment: Or even 30GB (on screenshout)

Comment: Yes, one snapshot. But i don't use it

Comment: As per the blog note in the link provided earlier: ***IMPORTANT**: If the virtual disk you want to resize is attached to a virtual machine with snapshots, you will need to delete these snapshots so that all disk state information is merged into the base virtual disk VDI file.*

Comment: OK. Can i delete snapshot for now?
Coz i can't

Comment: Do you have the backup of original virtual disk? If yes, restore that and then try.

Comment: So. I tried to delete old VDI with snapshots, then i delete snapshots.
Then i connect VDI_backup, which i create yestarday. 
And it seems like all data wiped from disk. Even `startx` is `not found`.

So it's my system right after installation 2 years ago.
Any chance to give my system back? If no - i just go and install new system

Comment: You mean backup itself is not working and you deleted the working copy too?

Comment: No no no. I mean the backup working like it 2-years-old backup. But i create it yestarday. I think some of my actions wiped all data

Comment: But, if you formalize your answer i can close this question and will check your answer

Comment: Not good if the data is lost.Did it solve the original problem of not extending the partition size?

Comment: Nope, coz VDI-backup was created before resize. But i think, if i resize it for now it would work.